# How to locate and click on a record from a dynamic table in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests

My code is below which works.Can anyone suggests a better way?

WebElement tasktable=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody"));

```
List<WebElement> rows=tasktable.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));

System.out.println("Number of rows:"+rows.size());
String sColValue="Test1";
//String sRowValue="Status";
System.out.println("Searching for : "+ sColValue);  
 for(int rnum=1;rnum<=rows.size();rnum++)

    {

String sValue = null;
String rValue=null;
sValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr["+rnum+"]/td[2]")).getText();
Thread.sleep(3000);
System.out.println("Name:"+ sValue);    
if(sValue.equalsIgnoreCase(sColValue))

    {
    System.out.println("Found : "+ sValue); 
    rValue = driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr["+rnum+"]/td[2]")).getText();
    System.out.println("Status:"+ rValue);
    Actions action= new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr["+rnum+"]/td[2]"))).doubleClick().build().perform();
    new Actions(driver).doubleClick(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/table/tbody/tr["+rnum+"]/td[2]"))).perform();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    break;
    }
else {
    System.out.println("Name:"+ sColValue+ "is not found"); 
}
```

Comment: You use absolute `XPath`. This is not a good idea. Show `HTML` of target elements to get nice relative `XPath` :) ..or other more flexible selector. Also you might need to check this http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: Below is the HTML

Comment: <div style="outline-style:none;" __gwt_cell="cell-gwt-uid-158" tabindex="0">Referral Approved</div>                                                                           is one of the rows in the table

Answer (score 0):

To find provided in comments element use following `XPath`:

```
//div[text()="Referral Approved"]
```

Comment: the code has to check for the value in each row in the table and select the record when the value matches